# There is other ways to install Ubuntu? (not wubi, not live CD)

Tags: windows-7, wubi

I had problems while installing ubuntu 12.04 on a samsung laptop, the problem is the AHCI sysmtem, after a lot of searching, I found that this is almost impossible to "fix" and the only way i found is too much work.

I want to install Ubuntu in the 110GB free partition of my hard drive, along with windows.

I have a 150GB Windows partition, a 200GB documents partition, and I want to use 110 GB for Ubuntu.

The problem is that with the liveCD the installer and gparted shows that my entire hard drive is unallocated (the problem of AHCI).

The only way to fix this is to do a lot of work, with a lot of risk, so the question is whether I can install Ubuntu without using either the LiveCD or Wubi.

Comment: Have you tried the [alternate CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) (go here and click "Text-based installer"), or for your convenience: [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why exactly you don't want wubi? Does not work, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Ubuntu Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&release=&bits=) (with these [official installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)).

Comment: I think the original poster actually wants to install a standard Ubuntu installation...but from inside Windows. The OP has used Wubi before (as indicated in the question). The question is a bit unclear, but I think by "a free space" the OP means "to unpartitioned space outside my Windows system."

Comment: @EliahKagan with Wubi you can install Ubuntu in other partitions, too.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think.

Comment: The quiestion i8s updated now

Comment: @TheGatorade Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misread your question, but you may want to consider using an alternate installer(text based, using keyboard for option selection), available [here](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) for i386 and [here](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso) for AMD64, or even the netboot CD, available [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) for AMD64 and [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) for i386.

Comment: Neither option uses AHCI, I believe.

Comment: The text based installer will alow me to install ubuntu without the problem of AHCI?

Comment: You may actually need to disable AHCI, or set it to SATA in your BIOS. If you can tell me more about your BIOS, I can help you more.

Comment: Well the problem is that I cnat turn it off, when I try it, just give me an error and reboot, the other option is auto, but is the same result that if I use it in ON.

Comment: Just try the netboot: You'll only need to download about 20 MiB for the mini image and it'll let you partition before downloading. Check that your disk shows up as partitioned.

Comment: How is the netboot?
Is as easier as the livecd install or is the text based installer?

Comment: @MauricioAndrés the netboot is not easier, per se. It is about the same as the text-based installer except  that it downloads Ubuntu during installation, which allows you to automatically get the newest versions of all of the packages. It is simpler in terms of installer functionality, nut quite useful.

Answer (score -1):

As much as I know you can install on a free space but not with wubi, you have a usb installer or a CD/DVD installer of Ubuntu to install and during the selection of partitions in the install just select the free space option.